# Proof of continuous mapping theorem, convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of the continuous mapping theorem regarding convergence in probability on Wikipedia [1].
Can someone please explain to me how this inequality follows?
$\Pr\big(\big|g(X_n)-g(X)\big|>\varepsilon\big) \leq
    \Pr\big(|X_n-X|\geq\delta\big) + \Pr(X\in B_\delta) + \Pr(X\in D_g).$

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Convergence_in_probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following events. $A := \{ \left| g(X_n) - g(X) \right| \gt \epsilon \}$, $B := \{ \left| X_n - X \right| \gt \epsilon \}$, $C:= \{ X \in D_g \}$, and $D := \{ X \in B_\delta \}$.

On the Wikipedia page referenced in your question, in the line just before the inequality quoted in your question, it is explained that we have
$$
A \subseteq B \cup C \cup D.
$$
From this we get by using basic properties of measures (actually, we're using monotonicity and subadditivity, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics))
$$
Pr(A) \leq Pr(B \cup C \cup D) \leq Pr(B) + Pr(C) + Pr(D).
$$
This is the inequality from the Wikipedia page.