# Show that $f(X_{n}) \rightarrow_{p} f(X)$.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $X_{n} \rightarrow_{p} X$ and $f$ is continuous. Show that $f(X_{n}) \rightarrow_{p} f(X)$.

$X_{n} \rightarrow_{p} X$ means for all $\epsilon >0, \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}[|X_{n}-X|\geq \epsilon]=0$

HINT:
You can use the following sets $$B_{\delta}=\{x| \text{ exists } y \text{ with } |x-y|<\delta \text{ and } |f(x)-f(y)|\ge \epsilon \}, \{ |f(X_{n})-f(x)|\geq \epsilon \}, \{|X_{n}-X|\geq \epsilon \} \text{ and } \{x \in B_{\delta} \}$$

But I don't know how to use it

Comment: No exactly, unless we can prove that the definition of $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}[|X_{n}-X|\geq \epsilon]=0$ US equivalent to the definition of the subsequences

Comment: Or does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254606/proof-of-continuous-mapping-theorem-convergence-in-probability

Comment: Thanks that helped me